# Foundation vs Enterprise Cumulative updates

Tags: unsafe-updates

I'm going through my test builds and I am curious if I should be installing Foundation CU's then installing Enterprise CU's on top of them?

I am working with Enterprise SP and to me it doesn't make sense. But I'm wondering what supportive evidence is out there that states it is necessary or unnecessary.

On another note if I understand correctly, I should need to install a CU from OCT 2010 on a fresh server, rather go for the most recent as it will have a roll up of all changes minus the service pack to date.

Comment: Found this post by Todd Klindt that covered the CU's looks like from the comment stream that it doesn't seem to impact things...if you install foundation CU's first then Server.... http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=224 any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the newer CUs for SharePoint 2010 it's not necessary according to [Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sharepoint/ff800847.aspx)

> The packaging of cumulative updates changed as of August 31, 2011 ... As a result of the new packaging, it is no longer necessary to install the SharePoint Foundation cumulative update and then install the SharePoint Server cumulative update

On a new Installation/Upgrade I'd go for:

- Install with SP1 slipstreamed in
- Perform upgrade of databases if from SP2007
- Add December 2011 CU

[Todd Klindt](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=320) has a good resource